# Running Django migrations on dockerized project

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a `Django` project running in multiple `Docker` containers with help of `docker-compose`. The source code is attached from directory on my local machine. Here's the compose configuration file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  core:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8001:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Although the application starts as it should, I can't run migrations, because every time I do `manage.py makemigrations ...` I receive:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Obviously I can open `bash` inside the `core` container and run `makemigrations` from there, but then the migration files are created inside the container which is very uncomfortable.

In my project's settings the database is configured as:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

As docker postgres image is accessible at `localhost:5432` I tried changing database host in settings to:

```
'HOST': '0.0.0.0'
```

But then when firing up the containers with `docker-compose up` I'm receiving:

```
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: 
Connection refused
Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
...
```

How should I configure database in `settings.py` so that `Django` can access it to create migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your docker-compose configurations are not correct. You forgot to link services

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  core:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8001:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
    links: # <- here
      - db
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as earlier:  `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: @StanRedoute Have you restarted your containers after updating configuration? `docker-compose down && docker compose up`. This should work, if it is still not working, we need more info

Comment: I have rebuilt compose with `--no-cache` to make a clean build and during firing up the `compose up` I received: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "db" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` Looks like `links` did the trick but Django itself can't access the link to db?

Comment: @StanRedoute this means your backend have started before `db` container was ready read more about this issue in https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/