# Django docker - could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: django, docker

I'm relatively new to Django and Docker and am following a tutorial to build a mini application. However, I'm getting stuck with the following error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

My docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
 version: '3'
 services:
  db:
     image: 'postgres'
     ports:
       - '5432'
  core:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
```

My settings.py file contains the database:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': 5432,
}
}
```

I've seen the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573313/docker-compose-with-django-could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-name-o) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552639/running-django-migrations-on-dockerized-project) however both have not fixed the issue.

Would appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Can you keep postgres container running and restart only django container and tell me if you still getting the same error ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mostafa. Apologies I'm still quite new to Docker so may need a hand doing that. I've stopped docker. How can I just get the Postgres container running? Thanks.

Comment: `docker-compose restart core` this will restart the application without the database so make sure that the database is running first then execute the command

Comment: Thanks. Still have the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that the postgres container was up and have not restarted while you restarted the application? can you check the up time through `docker ps` ?

Comment: See uptime:

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
189666f6a2b7        vision_core         "python3 manage.py r…"   4 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp    vision_core_1
af5402d6495f        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:32769->5432/tcp   vision_db_1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189737/discussion-between-mostafa-hussein-and-avocet).

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you are trying to reach the db which is running in one container from another container? If yes - the following could potentially help, at least it helped me when I had similar issues.

Try to define *networks* config in addition to *links* in your compose file, create a network with some name and define it in both services. Like described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks), as the docks on [*links*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) config recommend to do that.

Something like this for your case:

```
version: '3'
 services:
  db:
     image: 'postgres'
     ports:
       - '5432'
     networks:
      some_network:
  core:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      some_network:
  networks:
   some_network:
```

It helped me to resolve the host name to connect to the db.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of redefining the networks, use

```
docker-compose down -v
```

*to stop all containers and remove all cached data.*

Then

```
docker-compose up
```

*to restart from scratch*.

Answer (score 5):

I had to use `docker-compose up` to make sure my `db` container was running.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for several days for the solution to this issue. Here's what I did:

1 - I copied the postgresql.conf.sample file from my postgres container to my project folder
you must get in to `cd usr/share/postgresql`
with `docker exec -it yourcontainer` bash

2 - I changed its name to `postgresql.conf`

3 - I modified these variables in  `postgresql.conf`

```
    listen_addresses = '*'
    port = 5432             
    max_connections = 100           
    superuser_reserved_connections = 3
    unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'
```

4 - I added it to my Dockerfile

```
COPY postgresql.conf      /tmp/postgresql.conf
```

5 - settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'testing',
        'PASSWORD': 'tests',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

6 - I did `docker-compose up -build` again

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue recently, i solved it by adding postgres environment variables to db in my docker-compose.yml file like so

```
version: '3'
 services:
  db:
     image: 'postgres'
     ports:
       - '5432'
     environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=booksdb
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  core:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
```

Answer (score 1):

In my specific case, I had postgres without any version, so postgres image gets updated and the db (postgres) container won't get up

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works for me from official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

then run those commands:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

```
docker-compose logs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker exec -it "container_name" python3 manage.py migrate
```

This works for me. Make sure of the path to the manage.py file is correct.