# Connecting to postgres instance that is running via docker on my ubuntu server

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

How can I connect to my postgresql instance when I am running it via docker.

In my docker-compose I have the image defined as follows:

```
db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    #container_name: db
    volumes:
      - "/home/data/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    restart: always
```

I installed the client only:

```
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client
```

I installed the psql client on ubuntu, and I try to connect to it but can't seem to connect successfuly.

> psql -h db -p 5432 -U postgres
>
> psql: could not translate host name
> "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

I tried different hosts like localhost, 127.0.0.1 and docker_db_1 and they all didn't work.

Comment: Try adding `link`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081675/django-docker-could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-nodename-nor-serv

Answer (score 1):

You did not publish any port so you will not able to connect from the host. You need to publish port to connect container from your Host machine.

```
db:
  image: postgres:9.4
  container_name: db
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

Also, you should use `localhost` if you try to connect from Host, DB is only reachable within docker-compose network

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

or you can also verify inside the container

```
db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

to check connection with installing client on host

```
docker exec -it db bash -c "psql -U postgres"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the OS cannot translate the host name `db` into an IP address. You may need to add `hostname: db` into your `docker-compose.yml` file