# Docker Django can't translate hostname to address

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I want to deploy my django w postgres thanks to docker and I get an error like: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`

This is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment: 
        POSTGRES_USER: alban
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ***
        POSTGRES_DB:  plateforme
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build: ./plateforme_v2_1
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is my setting.py :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'plateforme',
        'USER': 'alban',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Does anyone here already get this problem ?

Thx

Comment: Are you using docker or docker-compose to run it?

Comment: @Sayse i'm using docker-compose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django docker - could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081675/django-docker-could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-nodename-nor-serv)

Comment: Where specifically are you trying to connect to the database?  (You can't from a `RUN` instruction in a Dockerfile, for example.)  Can you show enough of your application code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: can u use this image: postgres:11

Answer (score 0):

ur config should be like that ::

```
 DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
            "NAME": 'postgres',
            "USER": 'alban',
            "PASSWORD":'******',
            "HOST": 'db',
            "PORT": 5432,
        }
    }
```